# Database Backup/Restore exists in Azure Vs Traditional on-prem SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Just wondering if someone can fill me in on how Azure Native database works in terms of database backup and restore. I cannot see a way to have the DBA options to do a backup and restore using a GUI, I am guessing that it no longer exists in the same way you would in a traditional on-prem world due to the elastic nature in native Azure.

If anyone can shed some light on this and what is the alternative on creating a backup or even restoring in the event of a failure?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Backups are managed by the service, providing point-in-time restore from 7-35 days depending on the service level. You don't need to do anything unless you want to opt in to [Long Term Backup Retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview).

Read [Automated backups - Azure SQL Database & Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database)